# Show field if it has contents on Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, custom-field

I have a custom field set that is look to display like so:

```
<p><strong>Lease Rate:</strong>
        <?php the_field('lease_rate'); ?>
      </p>
      <p> <strong>NNN Expenses:</strong>
        <?php the_field('nnn'); ?>
      </p>
      <p> <strong>Monthly Rent:</strong>
        <?php the_field('rent'); ?>
      </p>

       <p> <strong>Site Area:</strong>
        <?php the_field('site_area'); ?>
      </p>
      <p><strong>Sale Price:</strong>
      <?php the_field('building_size'); ?></p>
      <p><strong>Building Size:</strong>
      <?php the_field('Address'); ?></p>
      <p><strong>Contact Name:</strong>
      <?php the_field('contact_name'); ?></p>
      <p><strong>Phone Number:</strong>
      <?php the_field('phone_number'); ?></p>
```

I need to change it so that:
IF the field is filled in, THEN the title shows up.

For example, if `the_field lease_rate` has a value then the paragraph "Lease Rate" shows up.

I was thinking some kind of if statement then echoing the p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ACF API's [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) to test for the existence of data:

```
if( $lease_rate = get_field('lease_rate') ){
    ?>
    <p><strong>Lease Rate:</strong>
        <?php echo $lease_rate; ?>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: wow, yup, that easy huh? thank you very much!!!!